# Zenity GUI for chattr and lsattr

Tags: bash, zenity

*Description:*

Hello *Stackers*, i'm currently making a zenity GUI for the command `chattr`. What i'm trying to do is to show and change the attributes of a file using `zenity --list --checklist` to tick the attributes that i want an so, **but the main issue that i'm facing is that i do not know whats the order of** `lsattr` **output, something like:** `-------------e-- file`

*Code sample:*

```
attr=("A" "Solo escritura" "a" "No actualizar" "c" "Comprimido" "C" "No copiar en escritura" "D" "Actualización de directorio sincrónica" "d" "Ignorar en backup" "E" "Error de compreción" "e" "Usando extents" "h" "Archivo enorme" "I" "Indexación hashed trees" "i" "Archivo inmutable" "j" "Registro de datos" "s" "Borrado seguro" "S" "Actualización sincrónica" "T" "Directorio tope" "t" "Archivo sin cola" "u" "Deshacer borrado" "X" "Acceso crudo dec compreción" "Z" "Archivo comprimido sucio" "-v" "Generar verción de archivo")

fileattr=$(lsattr "$file") ; j=0 ; k=1

for (( i=1; i<=15; i++ )); do
    [[ "${fileattr:$i:1}" != "-" ]] && values+="true ${attr[$j]} ${attr[$k]//' '/_} " && setted+="${attr[$j]} " ||\
    values+="false ${attr[$j]} ${attr[$k]//' '/_} "
    ((j+=2)) ; ((k+=2))
done

zenity --list --checklist --column="Estado" --column="Atributo" --column="Descripción" ${values}
```

*Code explanation:*

1. `attr` is an array and is ordered using this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr)
2. The `for` loop runs 15 times (it's equal to the amount of file attributes returned by `lsattr`), and in each go it validates for not setted attributes "-", if an attribute is set then append "true attr[j] attr[k]" to `values` and append the attribute to `setted` (for later on purposes) or append "false attr[j] attr[k]" to `values`
3. Finally call `zenity` with the collected `values`

*Launching output:*

[Zenity window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFN2O.png)
It tells me that the "s" attribute is set but thats not true because the `lsattr` output is `-------------e-- file`. I have noticed that there are more attributes in the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) than in the `lsattr` output

*Note:*

I know, maybe i'm not using the correct aproach, so if you can find a better way to do it, i'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associative arrays will be useful in this task.

Let's define a list of all the possible attributes:

```
valueList=acdeijstuACDST
```

Let's define an associative array to store the values:

```
declare -A valueMap
```

Initialize the map with all `false` values for all attributes:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#valueList}; i++)); do
    name=${valueList:i:1}
    valueMap[$name]=false
done
```

Loop over characters in `fileattr` to update values in the map to `true`:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 16; i++)); do
    name=${fileattr:i:1}
    [[ $name != - ]] && valueMap[$name]=true
done
```

Combine `valueMap` and your original `attr` to create an array of values to pass to Zenity:

```
zenityValues=()
for ((i = 0; i < ${#attr[@]}; i+=2)); do
    name=${attr[i]}
    description=${attr[i+1]}
    zenityValues+=(${valueMap[name]} "$name" "$description")
done
```

And finally call Zenity as you did, but passing `zenityValues` as an array:

```
zenity ... "${zenityValues[@]}"
```

Comment: It works like a charm, i didn't know that bash supports associative arrays, but it's a bit dissapointing that a for loop is required in order to fill them, also i didn't know that using an array to fill zenity columns would let you use whitespaces, that's brilliant.